# How to use only the REST API of Sails.js as a backend for a Hybrid HTML5 App

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, sails.js, intel-xdk

I am developing a Group Chat App using Intel XDK (App Framework). I see lot of examples on creating a chat application on web, but never came across using Sails's REST API as backend only service which can be used within a HTML5 app.

If you have any insights about the same, please do advise me.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sails also provides option to skip front end things by using the arguments `--no-frontend`

Example: `sails new my-api --no-frontend`

It will produce the following folder structure

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you simply delete Gruntfile.js and the views, tasks, and assets directories you will be left with a bare bones JSON api. You may choose to configure cors as well, which can be easily done using the documentation found in config/cors.js